# Is there a good way to keep track of source code files duplicated in multiple projects?

Tags: git, version-control, conventions, organization

Ideally I wouldn't want to have duplicates of the same or similar code in multiple locations, but sometimes I have to do it for distribution reasons, and some environments such as matlab don't support good code organization. Is there a good way to manage versions/updates of single source code files? I can think of git submodules and symlinks, but I was wondering if anyone has a more portable solution. I work with c/c++, matlab, and python mostly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used subtrees which worked really well for me 
http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/

The syntax for subtrees is somewhat long - so I wrote a couple of bash scripts to pull/push the library files

Generally I think they don't need symlinks as well. However I was developing a some library code for Joomla that required the library code to be placed in multiple folders across the site. To achieve this I had to symlink each folder in the subtree library to its corresponding location in the Joomla site's folder, this